# How to insert batch data into mysql in vb.net and c# using queries from a multiline textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, insert, batch-processing

I'm making a program in c# and vb.net with MySQL database. These two programs I'm making are identical, although it is written in different language but the functionality is the same. In these programs the queries are dynamic, the user will input his query in a multiline textbox and after pressing a button the query will be executed. But I have problem on inserting batch data. 
Below is an example of the queries from a multiline textbox, this was taken on a MySql dump file.

```
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11015', 'Mark', 'Caguia', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11016', 'James', 'CaguiaYap', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11017', 'Arwin', 'Santos', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11018', 'Chris', 'Lutz', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
INSERT INTO `blank` VALUES ('11019', 'Marcio', 'Laseter', 'C', '1/1/92', 'Philippines', '091083913121');
```

Here is my code in vb.net:

```
       Private Sub btnqueryrun_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnqueryrun.Click

       Try

        Dim StrQuery As String
        'txtQueryStr is the name of the multiline textbox
        StrQuery = txtQueryStr.Text

        sql = StrQuery
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cnn)

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "SQL Error",  MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try
    End Sub
```

And below is my code for c#:

```
    private void btnqueryrun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //txtQueryStr is the name of the multiline textbox
        strQuery = txtQueryStr.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;

        try
        {

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dt.Dispose();
            dt = new DataTable();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "SQL Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        }
```

Both programs run but, when I tried inserting over a thousand of data it returns an error, but when I checked my database, some data are inserted and there are 286 data inserted. The problem is that it limits only up to 286 data, but what I want to happen is to insert thousands of data.

Comment: So the first question is, what error are you getting?

Comment: it says i have an error on my sql syntax, and the error near '1-957-898-11' this is my mobile field in my database

Comment: And? What is the *exact* error message? What is the query that caused the error? .NET doesn't have limitations on statement execution or inserting a lot of data. Which statement inserts a mobile number ` 1-957-898-11`?  I'll bet it's in row 287. Is your database field a character or numeric field? If character, is it long enough to contain this value?

Comment: yes, error is at row 287. I've tried to change the format of 1-957-898-11 into 195789811 and it saves in my database, now i have 287 records in my database but it stops there and again it returns an error in the 288 row, it's still points on the mobile field with the format of 1-982-192-10. My mobile field is in varchar data type.

Comment: "you have an error in your Sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "1-957-898-11' at line 1 at MySql.Data. MysqlClient.MysqlStream.ReadPacket()..." this is the exact error i'm getting. The length by the way of my mobile field is 20.